# Datanode and nodemanger appear in jps but arent start correctly

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

when I execute jps command datanode and nodemanagger appears, but it seems that is not starting correctly, because if I check logs it seems that they arent running correctly.

In the namenode node when I format namenode and start the cluster I get a Version file in namenodefolder created automatically as I set in hdfs-site.xml:

```
clusterID=CID-76572234-4ef7-4e6a-8ec5-1f54fe22b17d
cTime=0
storageType=NAME_NODE
blockpoolID=BP-141486958-10.17.0.88-1463916426343
layoutVersion=-63
```

But in the node where is datanode this file its not created, the folder datanode that I set in hdfs-site.xml is created but its empty inside, I dont know if it is normal.

Nodemanager log:

```
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_91
************************************************************/
2016-05-22 11:41:11,219 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2016-05-22 11:41:12,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl$ContainerEventDispatcher
2016-05-22 11:41:12,265 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl$ApplicationEventDispatcher
2016-05-22 11:41:12,266 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.event.LocalizationEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService
2016-05-22 11:41:12,266 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServicesEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices
2016-05-22 11:41:12,266 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl
2016-05-22 11:41:12,267 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainersLauncherEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainersLauncher
2016-05-22 11:41:12,286 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerManagerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl
2016-05-22 11:41:12,286 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManagerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager
2016-05-22 11:41:12,326 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2016-05-22 11:41:12,397 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2016-05-22 11:41:12,398 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system started
2016-05-22 11:41:12,420 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.loghandler.event.LogHandlerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.loghandler.NonAggregatingLogHandler
2016-05-22 11:41:12,421 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.sharedcache.SharedCacheUploadEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.sharedcache.SharedCacheUploadService
2016-05-22 11:41:12,421 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: per directory file limit = 8192
2016-05-22 11:41:12,478 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: usercache path : file:/tmp/hadoop-hadoopadmin/nm-local-dir/usercache_DEL_1463913672424
2016-05-22 11:41:12,529 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.event.LocalizerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService$LocalizerTracker
2016-05-22 11:41:12,548 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@2dfaea86
2016-05-22 11:41:12,548 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : null
2016-05-22 11:41:12,549 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Physical memory check enabled: true
2016-05-22 11:41:12,549 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Virtual memory check enabled: true
2016-05-22 11:41:12,552 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: NodeManager configured with 8 G physical memory allocated to containers, which is more than 80% of the total physical memory available (3.9 G). Thrashing might happen.
2016-05-22 11:41:12,557 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Initialized nodemanager for null: physical-memory=8192 virtual-memory=17204 virtual-cores=8
2016-05-22 11:41:12,596 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2016-05-22 11:41:12,619 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 40484
2016-05-22 11:41:12,651 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ContainerManagementProtocolPB to the server
2016-05-22 11:41:12,651 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Blocking new container-requests as container manager rpc server is still starting.
2016-05-22 11:41:12,651 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2016-05-22 11:41:12,652 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 40484: starting
2016-05-22 11:41:12,661 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.security.NMContainerTokenSecretManager: Updating node address : ubuntuslave:40484
2016-05-22 11:41:12,668 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2016-05-22 11:41:12,669 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8040
2016-05-22 11:41:12,671 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.api.LocalizationProtocolPB to the server
2016-05-22 11:41:12,672 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8040: starting
2016-05-22 11:41:12,672 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2016-05-22 11:41:12,673 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Localizer started on port 8040
2016-05-22 11:41:12,675 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: ContainerManager started at ubuntuslave/10.17.0.89:40484
2016-05-22 11:41:12,675 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: ContainerManager bound to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:0
2016-05-22 11:41:12,676 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.WebServer: Instantiating NMWebApp at 0.0.0.0:8042
2016-05-22 11:41:12,749 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2016-05-22 11:41:12,758 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter: Unable to initialize FileSignerSecretProvider, falling back to use random secrets.
2016-05-22 11:41:12,763 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.nodemanager is not defined
2016-05-22 11:41:12,771 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter)
2016-05-22 11:41:12,773 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context node
2016-05-22 11:41:12,773 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2016-05-22 11:41:12,773 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2016-05-22 11:41:12,776 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: adding path spec: /node/*
2016-05-22 11:41:12,777 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: adding path spec: /ws/*
2016-05-22 11:41:12,786 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 8042
2016-05-22 11:41:12,786 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2016-05-22 11:41:12,813 INFO org.mortbay.log: Extract jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.1.jar!/webapps/node to /tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_8042_node____19tj0x/webapp
2016-05-22 11:41:13,010 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:8042
2016-05-22 11:41:13,010 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Web app /node started at 8042
2016-05-22 11:41:13,316 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Registered webapp guice modules
2016-05-22 11:41:13,324 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at masternode/10.18.0.50:8031
2016-05-22 11:41:13,417 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Sending out 0 NM container statuses: []
2016-05-22 11:41:13,426 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Registering with RM using containers :[]
2016-05-22 11:41:33,471 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server
```

datanode log:

```
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_91
************************************************************/
2016-05-22 11:40:40,852 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2016-05-22 11:40:41,523 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2016-05-22 11:40:41,607 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2016-05-22 11:40:41,607 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2016-05-22 11:40:41,612 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockScanner: Initialized block scanner with targetBytesPerSec 1048576
2016-05-22 11:40:41,614 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Configured hostname is ubuntuslave
2016-05-22 11:40:41,620 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting DataNode with maxLockedMemory = 0
2016-05-22 11:40:41,644 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Opened streaming server at /0.0.0.0:50010
2016-05-22 11:40:41,646 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Balancing bandwith is 1048576 bytes/s
2016-05-22 11:40:41,646 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Number threads for balancing is 5
2016-05-22 11:40:41,739 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2016-05-22 11:40:41,750 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter: Unable to initialize FileSignerSecretProvider, falling back to use random secrets.
2016-05-22 11:40:41,768 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.datanode is not defined
2016-05-22 11:40:41,776 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter)
2016-05-22 11:40:41,779 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context datanode
2016-05-22 11:40:41,780 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2016-05-22 11:40:41,780 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2016-05-22 11:40:41,796 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 52013
2016-05-22 11:40:41,796 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2016-05-22 11:40:41,990 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@localhost:52013
2016-05-22 11:40:42,109 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.web.DatanodeHttpServer: Listening HTTP traffic on /0.0.0.0:50075
2016-05-22 11:40:42,298 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: dnUserName = hadoopadmin
2016-05-22 11:40:42,298 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: supergroup = supergroup
2016-05-22 11:40:42,343 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
2016-05-22 11:40:42,361 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 50020
2016-05-22 11:40:42,388 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Opened IPC server at /0.0.0.0:50020
2016-05-22 11:40:42,400 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Refresh request received for nameservices: null
2016-05-22 11:40:42,424 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting BPOfferServices for nameservices: <default>
2016-05-22 11:40:42,436 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to masternode/10.18.0.50:9000 starting to offer service
2016-05-22 11:40:42,444 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 50020: starting
2016-05-22 11:40:42,445 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2016-05-22 11:41:02,555 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: masternode/10.18.0.50:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); maxRetries=45
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>masternode:8031</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>masternode:8032</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>masternode:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
<value>masternode:8033</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
<value>masternode:8088</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>masternode:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>file:///home/hadoopadmin/hadooptmp</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>file:///home/hadoopadmin/hadooptmp</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

masters file:

```
masternode
```

slaves file:

```
ubuntuslave
```

Do you understand why its not working?

Comment: datanode is unable to connect to namenode. is this a pseudo dist setup or cluster setup?

Comment: Cluster steup with two nodes. Im trying to have a master node and a salve node with the datanode. With jps command the datanode appear in the salve node but in the logs it seems that its not running properly..

Comment: did you format the namenode after setup and also did you set the tmp dir?

Comment: I update the question with the configs I did, I did the same configs on the slave node.

Comment: I dont know if dfs.name.dir and dfs.data.dir can have the same folder but I already tried with same and different folders and I get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at datanode logs it looks like the error is coming because of  NameNode. It seems that namenode is down. Since NameNode is down, Datanode is not able to start properly.

```
Here is what you can do : 
A. start the namenode.
B. verify that namenode is running properly.
C. start the datanode. verify it started properly.
D. Run your spark application
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but the namenode is working properly. Just the datanode dont start properly.

Comment: Are you able to ssh from slave to master? Also datanode is trying to connect to wrong namenode port (8020).  In core-site.xml  change the fs.defaultFS to hdfs://masternode:9000/ .

Comment: I already try with 9000, now I put 8020 to test different if it works. Yes I can ssh from master to slave without password and from slave to master with password.